# Drupal independent exposed filters

Tags: 7, views

I have a view with 4 exposed filters and I need them to work independent from each other without combining their values in url.

The view should only filter by the last clicked filter.

I've been trying grouping filters with AND or OR operators but no luck yet.

How can I force that behavior?

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot of your and/or operators screen that you have?  Just to make sure the error isn't in that setup?

Comment: Hi! [Here](http://i.imgur.com/iFFWL.png) it is, the way it's configured with OR joins filter results when clicking each filter. Thank you

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question.  I thought you weren't getting the OR's and AND's to work, which work very well for me.  But now that I re-read your question, I see that you're trying to *ignore* all filters except for the last one, which is not what those operators can help you achieve... I'm not sure how I'd do that at the moment.  Hopefully someone else will jump in!!!

Comment: Thank you anyway! I hope so or i need to change the way i'm doing it..